# Bring to derived object the assignment operator from base (prior to C++11)

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, c++98

I have a code similar to this:

```
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    B &operator =(const T &) { return *this; }
};

struct D : B<int> {};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Which fails:

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
   d = 0;
   ~ ^ ~
note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const D' for 1st argument
struct D : B<int> {};
       ^
note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'D' for 1st argument
struct D : B<int> {};
       ^
```

The error is easy to spot and understand: `D` lacks of assignment operator with `int`, even if its base class have it. From [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) onwards we can solve this issue "lifting" to the derived object the assignment operator from the base object:

```
struct D : B<int> { using B::operator =; /* Easy fix! */ };
```

But I'm working on a [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) project, so this fix isn't available. How was this solved prior to C++11?

Comment: It sounds strange. The using detective comes from earlier C++. What error do you get in C++98? Maybe `using B<int>::operator =;` will work.

Comment: The use of `using` directive in this context is a [C++11 feature](https://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting).

Comment: Your link: **C++98, we can "lift" a set of overloaded functions from a base class into a derived class** - nothing about C++11

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster It's a `using` _declaration_ (not _directive_) and it works in C++98. It's `using` declarations of constructors that doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, the program(with *using declaration*) works with C++98. [Working Demo with C++98](https://cppinsights.io/s/4a0ddcc6).

That is, a using declaration for the assignment operator of the base class inside the derived class is allowed by C++98. Here is the relevant [text](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/pdf/nov97-2/body.pdf) from the standard:

> If an **assignment operator brought from a base class into a derived class** scope has the signature of a copy-assignment operator for the derived class (12.8), the using-declaration
> does not by itself suppress the implicit declaration of the derived class copy-assignment operator; the
> copy-assignment operator from the base class is hidden or overridden by the implicitly-declared copy-
> assignment operator of the derived class, as described below.

(emphasis mine)

Note again that the important thing is that the using declaration for the assignment operator of base class is allowed.

Now, you can define an assignment `operator=` for the derived class that explicitly uses the base class as shown below:

```
struct D : B<int> {
    D& operator=(const int& obj) {
        B<int>::operator=(obj); //use base class assignment operator
        return *this;
    }
    
};
```

Comment: It was likely an *extension* in some compilers, prior to C++11 (or was it C++17?).

Comment: @AdrianMole I think C++98 supported `using declarations` and so OP's assumption that it wouldn't work with C++98 seems incorrect. Though i have to look in the old documentation if you ask for citation. That is, i don't think it was a compiler extension.

Comment: I just tested it with MSVC 2005 and the using clause worked. I'm totally confused because I remember testing something similar back in 2012 with an old version of MSVC and it didn't work.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I've added a statement from the standard which implies that a using declaration for the assignment operator of base class is allowed. Check out my updated answer. There i have also given a reference(link).

Comment: @AdrianMole I've added a statement from the standard which implies that a using declaration for the assignment operator of base class is allowed. Check out my updated answer. There i have also given a reference(link).

Comment: Ted's answer has cleared up the confusion, I think.

Answer (score 5):

`using` declarations for inheriting base class methods already works in C++98.

It's `using` declarations to inherit *constructors* that doesn't.

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
    B(const T&) {}
    B &operator=(const T&) { return *this; }
};

struct D : B<int> {
    // using B<int>::B;           // error, constructors can't be inherited
    using B<int>::operator=;
};
```

and you then need to implement one that initializes the base class:

```
struct D : B<int> {
    D(int v) : B(v) {}          // this works
    using B<int>::operator=;    // and this too
};
```

Comment: That might explain my confusion!

Comment: This is the best answer here IMO because it makes proper use of the language features available.

Answer (score 3):

> But I'm working on a c++98 project, so this fix isn't available. How was this solved prior to C++11?

Define an `operator=` in `D` that calls `B::operator=`:

```
struct D : B<int> {
    D& operator=(const int &rhs) {
        B<int>::operator=(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Heh - You were ~30 seconds faster than I. But, our code for the `D::operator=` is so good, maybe we should leave it posted twice. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the required operator function to your derived class and call the corresponding base class operator from that:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct B {
    B& operator = (const T&) { return *this; }
};

struct D : B<int> {
    D& operator = (const int& rhs) {
        B<int>::operator = (rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d = 0;

    return 0;
}
```